# ¿Por qué me sale estos errores en GIT al hacer push desde mi rama nueva?

Tags: git, bitbucket

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
He creado una nueva rama en mi local y ahora quiero hacer git push y me salta estos errores, no entiendo porque me sale este error.